# Krull Dimension

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, krull-dimension

For all $n$, I need to find examples of rings $A\subset B$ such that:

i) $\dim A-\dim B\gt n$

ii) $\dim B-\dim A\gt n$

(where $\dim$ is the *Krull dimension*)

Comment: is this a homework problem?

Comment: Nope, I would have said if it was. :)

Comment: Hopefully, you are not required to satisfy both (i) and (ii) with the same $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[x_0, \dots, x_n] \subset \mathbb{Q}(x_0, \dots, x_n)$.

Comment: When you're right, you're right. thanks. 